# YouTube analytics sample API request giving 403 Forbidden with content owner login

Tags: http-status-code-403, youtube-analytics-api

Getting 403 error from youtube analytics own API samples when we are trying to get revenue/content owner data by content owner login itself (youtube partner enabled). Please see the attached link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8ycF.png

```
[{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

Comment: No way to reproduce your problem... https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 0):

You need to be connected to a CMS account to retrieve revenue data from YouTube API.